# Unity: Using a random.range result from inside an iterator (rolling dice)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There's plenty of tutorials on how to make a dice script but for some reason I can't find one that shows how to have something happen based on the roll.  I know how to make random.range.  But that's too simple for a dice because you want to make the dice appear that it's rolling or spinning through the sides before stopping.  That seems to mean we use an iterator or IEnumerator or Coroutine and there lies the problem.  Those don't spit out the int result we need (at least not in the script I'm using).

Here's the dice script I've been using from a tutorial.  I haven't found a way to get the dice results to be visiable(usable) anywhere outside of the RollTheDice method.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dice : MonoBehaviour {

    private Sprite[] diceSides;

    private SpriteRenderer rend;

    private void Start () {

        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/");
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine("RollTheDice");
    }

    // Coroutine that rolls the dice
    private IEnumerator RollTheDice()
    {

        int randomDiceSide = 0;

        int finalSide = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            randomDiceSide = Random.Range(0, 5);

            rend.sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }

        finalSide = randomDiceSide + 1;

        Debug.Log(finalSide);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you rolling a 5 sided die? `Random.Range(0,5)` can only return 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. Also, `finalSide` will be 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a method that has an int as a parameter which does whatever you need to do with the int, then call that method inside of the coroutine with the result of each roll, before you yield.

Then you could call another method after the rolling completes if you would like.

E.g.:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dice : MonoBehaviour {

    private Sprite[] diceSides;

    private SpriteRenderer rend;

    private List<int> results;

    private void Start () {

        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("DiceSides/");
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine("RollTheDice");
    }

    private void UseResult(int result)
    {
        results.Add(result);
    }

    private void FinishResults()
    {
        foreach (int i : results)
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
        }
    }

    // Coroutine that rolls the dice
    private IEnumerator RollTheDice()
    {

        int randomDiceSide = 0;

        int finalSide = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            randomDiceSide = Random.Range(0, 5);

            rend.sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];

            UseResult(randomDiceSide);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }

        FinishResults();

        finalSide = randomDiceSide + 1;

        Debug.Log(finalSide);
    }
}
```

Note: Typed on phone, please excuse any syntax errors or other minor mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, IEnumerator RollTheDice() displays the throughout rolling process till the dice stops. Its final result can be accessed by rend.sprite when RollTheDice is Done.

Comment: And how would you do that? Just put int rend.sprite; outside of any method?